# Authenticating Angular2 using JWT tokens in Express

Tags: angular, express, jwt

This is really a simple login solution for my website. I use angular2 as front-end, pass the user and password as JSON to express server, find the user in my MongoDB using mongoose then give me a token back once it verified that the username and password is correct.

Take a look at my setup.

app.js where I require middleware

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('./config');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var productsRouter = require('./routes/productsRoute')();
var cartRouter = require('./routes/cartRoute')();
var userRouter = require('./routes/usersRoute')();

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('superSecret', config.secret);
```

my config.js

```
module.exports = {
    'secret': 'wingsareallineed',
}
```

and my usersRoute.js

```
  userRouter.route('/login')
    .post(function(req, res){
      console.log(user);
      mongoose.connect(url, function(err){
        users.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user){
          if(err) throw err;

          if(!user){
            res.json({success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'});
          } else if(user) {
            if(user.password != req.body.password){
              res.json({success: false, message: 'Authentican failed. Wrong password.'});
            } else {
              var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
                expiresInMinutes: 1440
              });
            }

            res.json({
              success: true,
              message: 'Success!',
              token: token
            });
          }
          mongoose.disconnect();
        });
      });
    });
```

When I press the login button, i get an *Internal Server Error*. Anything I missed?